# Graph Interpretation

Tags: data-visualization, categorical-data, interpretation

I would like to ask what could be the most possible interpretation of these two graphs attached. 
[image]

One of them depicts conditional probabilty p(Y|X) whereas the second one shows Y regressed on X. I find it strange that although one image shows explicitly that conditional probability of Y=1 decreases as x increases (no matter the binning), the other points out strong positive correlation in between X and Y.

In other words how to interpret positive coefficient in such a situation?

Comment: "p(Y|X)" is ambiguous--and therein may lie the solution to your problem.  Please specify whether this is intended to mean p(Y=1|X) or p(Y=2|X).  (I suspect it is the former, in which case the two plots are perfectly consistent in the information they portray but inconsistent in *how* they portray it: the right hand plot ought to reverse the vertical axis.)  How was the left hand plot constructed?

Answer (score 4):

I had to struggle to interpret your graphs. You do give most of the information needed but a little tersely. Here is my understanding.

1. Start with the right-hand graph. $y$ is a variable that takes on the values $1$ or $2$ only. $x$ is another variable that takes several different values between about $-1.4$ and $2.9$.
2. The right-hand graph shows a sloping line which is the least-squares regression of $y$ on $x$.
3. Move to the left-hand graph. The dark area shows the probability $P(y = 1|x)$ and the complementary lighter area shows the other probability. The text labels $0$ and $1$ on the left-hand $y$ axis appear therefore to be typos for $1$ and $2$ and refer to lower and upper shaded areas on the graph.

All that said, my best guess is that there's a mistake somewhere. After all, why are $y$ labelled $0$ and $1$ in the left-hand graph? Where there's one mistake, others often lurk nearby.

Incidentally, in software I use I always exploit the scope to give intelligible variable or column names, e.g. `price` or `systolic` or `area` not `y` or `x` or `z`.

I await with interest whether others can find a more ingenious explanation, but at first sight the graphs do seem contradictory to me.

EDIT: Note later comment:

Major clusters of values with high $x,y=2$ and/or low $x,y=1$ may be outvoting the other data points. So showing the marginal distributions too can only help to clarify.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Nick. In this case 'twos' on the right hand side pertain to 'ones' on the left-hand graph and 'ones' on the right-hand side are 'zeros' on the left-hand side (various kinds of graphs seem to encode levels of dummies differently given the default parameters).

Comment: Would you consider adding a rug/jitter to my graphs? May it be a case that high frequency of higher values (e.g we see a peak at 2.0) renders the slope coef positive?

Comment: On the graphs: Clearly the labelling is a detail here, but I'd call such mislabelling evidence for a bug, taking it as implied that it's not your mistake. I can't add a rug or jitter to your graphs, as I can't see the data.

Comment: But you are right. Major clusters of values with high $x, y = 2$ and/or low $x, y = 1$ may be outvoting the others. So showing the marginal distributions too can only help to clarify.

Comment: Nick, I think there may be a simpler explanation.  (To wit, there likely was no mistake in calculation, but only some confusion about what was actually done, as exacerbated by murky graphics and a poor choice of dummy variable coding.)  I await clarification from the OP to a comment to the question.

Comment: @whuber A mistake was my first guess. My second guess hedged bets.